# Explanation of path connected and connected

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that the ordered square is connected but not path connected.

It's connected because it's a linear continuum.  But its not path connected.  This is where I'm stuck.  So I took two points $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$.  The lines are the open neighborhood $U$ that contains both of those points.

Just by looking at the picture below, I'm stuck as to why its not path connected.

[image]

Sorry if the picture is poorly drawn, but I just learned how to use GIMP to sketch stuff out.

Comment: It’s actually the *lexicographically* ordered square; we can tell from the picture, but you really ought to specify the ordering.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.  I'm just trying to work out problems that deal with these problems because of a conceptual hurdle I am experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the interval from $\langle x_0,y_0\rangle$ to $\langle x_1,y_1\rangle$ contains uncountably many pairwise disjoint open sets, so it’s not separable. But a path is a continuous image of $[0,1]$, so ... ?

Comment: It it because we have an uncountable collection of disjoint sets contained in a connected set?

Comment: @jdla: No, it’s because the continuous image of a separable set is ... ?

Comment: a seperable set.

Comment: @jdla: There you go. And any space with uncountably many pairwise disjoint open sets must be non-separable: if $D$ is a dense set in that space, there has to be at least one member of $D$ in each of those open sets.